# c headers and .c files with structures and typedefs

Tags: c, include

I am having a wonderful time, as usual. This time it has to do with header files, structures, and my .c files being used in some main. I've tried about every permutation that makes sense, and I can't get a proper link. This is just a permutation I've tried:

header file:

```
struct MyHashMap;
struct node;
typedef struct MyHashMap MyHashMap;
typedef struct node node;
struct MyHashMap* myHashMapCreate();
void myHashMapPut(MyHashMap* obj, int key, int value);
int myHashMapGet(MyHashMap* obj, int key);
void myHashMapRemove(MyHashMap* obj, int key);
void myHashMapFree(MyHashMap* obj)
```

HashMap.c:

```
#include "HashMap.h"
struct MyHashMap;
struct node;

typedef struct MyHashMap MyHashMap;
typedef struct node node;

struct node{
    int key;
    int val;
    node* next;
};

struct MyHashMap{
    node** hashTable;
};

MyHashMap* myHashMapCreate() {
}

void myHashMapPut(MyHashMap* obj, int key, int value) {
...    
}

int myHashMapGet(MyHashMap* obj, int key) {
...
}

void myHashMapRemove(MyHashMap* obj, int key) {
...
}

void myHashMapFree(MyHashMap* obj) {
...
}
```

and the main file, some_application.c

```
#include "HashMap.h"

int main()
{
    MyHashMap * obj = myHashMapCreate();
}
```

these typedefs keep trampling my includes. And creating errors for me such as:

```
HashMap.c: In function ‘myHashMapFree’:
HashMap.c:8:1: warning: empty declaration
    8 | struct MyHashMap;
      | ^~~~~~
HashMap.c:9:1: warning: empty declaration
    9 | struct node;
      | ^~~~~~
HashMap.c:11:26: error: storage class specified for parameter ‘MyHashMap’
   11 | typedef struct MyHashMap MyHashMap;
```

It all makes sense to me, but the compiler and I are DEFINITELY not friends, yet. I don't know if we'll ever be friends. It's like that girl at the squash courts, I don't plan on stopping until something good, or bad happens.

Oh, and I tried compiling with:

```
gcc -o some_application some_application.c HashMap.c
```

Comment: The first two lines in the header are harmless but unnecessary — the `typedef` lines would suffice.  Your declaration `struct MyHashMap* myHashMapCreate();` is not a prototype; it says the function exists and what it returns, but the argument list is unspecified.  Any number of arguments may be supplied (unless you're using a C++ compiler — the rules are different in C++).  You need `struct MyHashMap* myHashMapCreate(void);` to say that the function takes no arguments.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the 4 lines after `#include "HashMap.h"` in the source file.  The header already provided those names.  In old C, you couldn't repeat a `typedef` — C90 and C99 did not allow it (see [C99 §6.7 Declarations ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7p3)), but C11 does ([C11 §6.7 Declarations ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p3)).

Comment: Which compiler are you using, and what options are you using?  With GCC 10.2.0 set pretty fussy (`gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes …`), I get no complaints.  Also, Apple `clang` (`Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)`) doesn't complain either, even if I add `-Weverything`.

Comment: Oh, did you notice that there's a semicolon missing at the end of the last declaration in the header.  I want to think that's a typo in the question, but it might throw everything off. Technically, `typedef` is a 'storage class' (which might account for the messages), but GCC and Clang give other messages than the ones you show.

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0.

I've tried a few ways, with and without the typedefs. It's quite fussy, and I can't be sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Well, I don't get similar messages with GCC 9.3.0 either.  I'm testing on a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I feel like a fool. Much time wasted over a semi-colon. But besides... you did help with the explanations about the typedef, which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Jonathan in the comments:

```
typedef struct MyHashMap MyHashMap;
typedef struct node node;
struct MyHashMap* myHashMapCreate(void);
void myHashMapPut(MyHashMap* obj, int key, int value);
int myHashMapGet(MyHashMap* obj, int key);
void myHashMapRemove(MyHashMap* obj, int key);
void myHashMapFree(MyHashMap* obj);
```

does suffice...